# Mysql does not store string contains swedish character

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, encoding

I am developing an application on Codeigniter and mysql with swedish language.
I am using utf8_general_ci Collation for the column which stores names in swedish characters.

In database.php in config directory of CodeIgniter setting are as follow

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Now when I save a string containing å (for example qwertåpoiutt). String after å is discarded and save in database before å (save only qwert).

at the same time if I run that query in phpmyadmin then entire string is stored.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You probably do not use utf8 throughout your entire application, from the html input to database insertion.

Comment: On webpage when I show that name I use utf8_encode()
when I receive data after form is posted , I use utf8_decode().

On the html page i have used meta tag 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: Why do you use utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() if you use utf8 throughout your application?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your field collation to utf8_swedish_ci or latin1_swedish_ci   in database table, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Truncated** text,

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8.  Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is utf8.

You apparently had hex `E5`, the latin1 encoding, for `å`, instead of the utf8 encoding: `C3A5`.